# passing query results to view (Codeigniter 2)

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am following a tutorial on Codeigniter 2. Unfortunately, I can't get the sample to work. I receive an error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: text1
>
> Filename: views/content_home.php
>
> Line Number: 14

**Controller:**

```
public function home()
    {

        $this->load->model('model_get');
        $data['results'] = $this->model_get->getData('home');

        $this->load->view('site_header');
        $this->load->view('site_nav');
        $this->load->view('content_home', $data);
        $this->load->view('site_footer');
    }
```

**Content Page / View:**

```
<div id="content">

        <?php

        foreach($results as $row) {

            $title = $row->title;
            $text1 = $row->text1;
            $text2 = $row->text2;
        }
        ?>

        <h1>Home Page von Milstink</h1>
        <p><?php echo $text1; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $text2; ?></p>


    </div>
```

**Model:**

```
<?php

class Model_get extends CI_Model {

    public function getData($page)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('pageData', array('page' => '$page'));
        return $query->result();

    }
}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: The message mentions that you have an undefined variable text1. `$row->text1` probably doesn't exist. Also, in your model remove the single quotes around page. Change to `array('page' => $page)`

Comment: hmmm.... you are right, thank you. I wrote '$page' when instead it's just $page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `$text1` doesn't exits. Change `'$page'` to `$page` in model.

```
class Model_get extends CI_Model {

public function getData($page)
 {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('pageData', array('page' => $page));
    return $query->result();

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in model code will be

```
<?php
```

class Model_get extends CI_Model {

```
public function getData($page)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('pageData', array('page' => $page));
    return $query->result();

}
```

}

in '$page' its compare database there are not data in this condition so its return empty row.

please try this.